# \hyperref error when using figure. Colors and too many }'s?

Tags: graphics, hyperref

I am having trouble with the `colorlinks=true` command with the `\hyperref` package. When I include it as well as the `\figure` command I get an error relating to colors. Excluding it allows the document to compile.

The error says

```
 Too many }'s

  \color@endbox ->\ color@endgroup \ group
```

Here is a simplified version of my code which produces the same error

```
\begin{document}

\href{www.google.com}{google}

\begin{figure}{h!}

\caption{what}

\includegraphics{pug.jpg}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and here are the packages I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, bm} 

\usepackage{dcolumn, multirow} 


\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure, float} 

% \graphicspath{ \input{501.TA} }

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{url} 

\usepackage{hyperref} % allows you to use hyperlinks

%\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % excluding this and the one below resolves the problem. Including either leads to the error message.

%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true} 


\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{section}{part}


%\usepackage{url}% allows including urls with \url{} field.

\singlespace
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (if I rearrange it so that the preamble comes first), both with the `colorlinks` option and with the `\hypersetup` command.

Comment: please fix your example so that it starts `\documentclass` and ends `\end{docuemnt}` and demonstrates the error, also unrelated `{h!}` will just typeset `h!` you presumably intended `[h!]` although that usually just generates a warning from latex, better to use `[htp]` to give latex a chance to position the float.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest you did several mistakes:

- !h goes between square brackets;
- I got an hyperref config clash because you declared to use hyperref three times in the preamble; it's enough one, adding the options, in this case colorlink=true, within square brackets;
- you declared to use the package url twice.

Change the code like this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, ams symb, bm} 
\usepackage{dcolumn, multirow} 
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure, float} 
% \graphicspath{ \input{501.TA} }
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url} 
%\usepackage{hyperref} % allows you to use hyperlinks
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % excluding this and the one below     resolves the problem. Including either leads to the error message.
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{section}{part}
%\usepackage{url}% allows including urls with \url{} field.
\singlespace 

\begin{document}
\href{www.google.com}{google}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\caption{what}
\includegraphics{picture.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```